# Datalist doesn't disappear when input is blurred

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I have an input with a datalist. Part of the behavior involves the input being blurred under certain conditions. When I call `blur()` however, the datalist doesn't go away like I expect and, even worse, clicking elsewhere on the screen doesn't cause it to go away either; I am forced to either click a different input on screen (not just any other element) or click back into that input and then click away to get it to go away. Am I missing something or is this just unavoidable?

The following is about as minimal as an example can be:

```js
document.getElementById('testinput').addEventListener('input', e => e.target.blur())
```

```html
<input id="testinput" type="text" list="testlist" />
<datalist id="testlist">
  <option>TestOption</option>
</datalist>
```

Other than unlinking the datalist from the input when I want to blur it, so that it no longer applies, is there anything else I can do to make this work? It seems like very basic behavior.

edit: unlinking alone isn't enough, since the autocomplete suggestions still show up and have the same behavior. You also need `autocomplete="off"` in addition to unlinking the datalist to get the expected behavior. Seems like a lot of hassle for what should be default behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest, this is not the best solution, but you can try deleting and returning the `list` attribute as needed. Example below:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('testinput');

element.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.blur()
});

element.addEventListener('focusin', e => {
  e.target.setAttribute('list', 'testlist'); 
})

element.addEventListener('focusout', e => {
  e.target.removeAttribute('list')
});
```

```html
<input id="testinput" type="text" list="testlist" />
<datalist id="testlist">
  <option>TestOption</option>
</datalist>
```

Or a more compact version, without the `focusin` and `focusout` events:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('testinput');

element.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.removeAttribute('list');
  e.target.blur();
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.setAttribute('list', 'testlist');
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="testinput" type="text" list="testlist" />
<datalist id="testlist">
  <option>TestOption</option>
</datalist>
```

With `autocomplete` you can try to solve in a similar way (toggling "on" | "off"):

```js
const element = document.getElementById('testinput');

element.addEventListener('input', e => {
  e.target.removeAttribute('list');
  e.target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
  e.target.blur();
  setTimeout(() => {
    e.target.setAttribute('list', 'testlist');
    e.target.setAttribute('autocomplete', 'on');
  });
});
```

```html
<input id="testinput" type="text" list="testlist" autocomplete="on" />
<datalist id="testlist">
  <option>TestOption</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: This is the solution I ended up using, with Autocomplete disabled entirely since I am fetching recommended results to fill the datalist with as the user types. Definitely hacky though. If I hadn't already finished and gotten it working *well enough*, I'd reimplement it from scratch with my own custom popup. I guess I'll go that route if it somehow breaks.